# Saving Keras models with Custom Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save

I am trying to save a Keras model in a H5 file. The Keras model has a **custom layer**.
When I try to **restore the model**, I get the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0fbff9b56a9d> in <module>()
      1 model.save('model.h5')
      2 del model
----> 3 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    319   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    320   if cls is None:
--> 321     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    322 
    323   cls_config = config['config']

ValueError: Unknown layer: CustomLayer
```

Could you please tell me how I am supposed to save and load weights of all the custom Keras layers too? (Also, there was no warning when saving, will it be possible to load models from H5 files which I have already saved but can't load back now?)

Here is the minimal working code sample (MCVE) for this error, as well as the full expanded message: [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18r5TDlVZR8SC1WBOXuYKk9f17edZN6y6?usp=sharing)

Just for completeness, this is the code I used to make my custom layer.
`get_config` and `from_config` are both working fine.

```py
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, k, name=None):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.k = k

    def get_config(self):
        return {'k': self.k}

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.multiply(input, 2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(name='input_layer', shape=(10,)),
    CustomLayer(10, name='custom_layer'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_layer')
])
model.save('model.h5')
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and I did what it says, right? I have implemented that, both the `get_config` and `from_config` functions. But they never save the whole model, they always just get away with saving weights.

Comment: @AnimeshSinha, The error can be resolved by replacing `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')` with `tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})`. However, it is resulting in other error. Your Google Colab is not accessible. Can you please provide access to it so that I can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @TensorflowWarriors, fixed the link. I will try the custom objects think.

Comment: @AnimeshSinha, Can you please confirm if using `Custom Objects` has resolved your problem.

Comment: No @TensorflowWarriors, this is the new error I am getting: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_input_shape'`. Made that edit in Colab too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Correction number 1 is to use `Custom_Objects` while `loading` the `Saved Model` i.e., replace the code,

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

with

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
```

Since we are using `Custom Layers` to `build` the `Model` and before `Saving` it, we should use `Custom Objects` while `Loading` it.

Correction number 2 is to add `**kwargs` in the `__init__` function of the Custom Layer like

```
def __init__(self, k, name=None, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.k = k
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Complete working code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, k, name=None, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.k = k
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def get_config(self):
        config = super(CustomLayer, self).get_config()
        config.update({"k": self.k})
        return config

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.multiply(input, 2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(name='input_layer', shape=(10,)),
    CustomLayer(10, name='custom_layer'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_layer')
])
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'model.h5')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})

print(new_model.summary())
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
custom_layer_1 (CustomLayer) (None, 10)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
output_layer (Dense)         (None, 1)                 11        
=================================================================
Total params: 11
Trainable params: 11
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Hi, is correction 2 necessary to save the model with the given custom layer? Thanks

Comment: Will the weights be passed automatically to the custom layer?

Answer (score 21):

You can provide manually the mapping `custom_objects` in the `load_model` method as mentioned in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62326857/8056572 but it can be tedious when you have a lot of custom layers (or any custom callables defined. e.g. metrics, losses, optimizers, ...).

Tensorflow provides a utils function to do it automatically: [tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/register_keras_serializable)

You have to update your `CustomLayer` as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, k, **kwargs):
        self.k = k
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config["k"] = self.k
        return config

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.multiply(input, 2)
```

---

Here is the complete working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, k, **kwargs):
        self.k = k
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config["k"] = self.k
        return config

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.multiply(input, 2)


def main():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.Input(name='input_layer', shape=(10,)),
            CustomLayer(10, name='custom_layer'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_layer')
        ]
    )
    print("SUMMARY OF THE MODEL CREATED")
    print("-" * 60)
    print(model.summary())
    model.save('model.h5')

    del model

    print()
    print()

    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
    print("SUMMARY OF THE MODEL LOADED")
    print("-" * 60)
    print(model.summary())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the corresponding output:

```
SUMMARY OF THE MODEL CREATED
------------------------------------------------------------
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
custom_layer (CustomLayer)   (None, 10)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
output_layer (Dense)         (None, 1)                 11        
=================================================================
Total params: 11
Trainable params: 11
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None


WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
SUMMARY OF THE MODEL LOADED
------------------------------------------------------------
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
custom_layer (CustomLayer)   (None, 10)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
output_layer (Dense)         (None, 1)                 11        
=================================================================
Total params: 11
Trainable params: 11
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```