# Difference between tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_dir) and tf.keras.model.save

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a keras model and want to save it as a tensorflow graph. Is there a difference between `tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_dir)` and `tf.keras.model.save`.

In both of these, I want to save in a `tensorflow` saved format and will not be using `h5` format. I understand `tf.saved_model.save` is more generic but if I am using a `keras` model are these two different in anyways.

Comment: Please let me know if the given answer ok for you. else you can share your doubt so we can update. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In general cases, there should not be any difference. To give a concrete answer, we can save the entire `tf. keras` model - one is **TensorFlow SavedModel** and another one is `.h5` format.

As you said, you have a `keras` model and wanted to save its graph. You can do this either

- `Model.save` or
- `tf.keras.models.save_model`

```
(1)
Model.save(
    filepath,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None,
    save_traces=True,
)

(2)
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    filepath,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None,
    save_traces=True,
)

(3)
# tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_dir)
tf.saved_model.save(model,
                    export_dir, 
                    signatures, 
                    options)
```

As you can see, all of them take the same argument too. I would recommend choosing **(1)** or **(2)**, easy to follow. Here is an example, I've trained a function model on the `CIFAR` data set and saved the model as follows with **(1)** and **(2)** approaches.

```
func_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=2, verbose = 1)
1s/step - loss: 2.7365 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1088
1s/step - loss: 1.8353 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3905

# with (1)
func_model.save('/content/1/', 
                save_format='tf', save_traces=False)
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/1/assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/1/assets

# with (2)
tf.keras.models.save_model(func_model, '/content/2/', 
                           save_format='tf', save_traces=False)
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/2/assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/2/assets
```

Load and re-train them

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import  load_model

x = load_model('.//1/') 
y = load_model('.//2/')

x.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=1, verbose = 1)
1s/step - loss: 1.0963 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6780

y.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=1, verbose = 1)
1s/step - loss: 1.0963 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6780
```

---

Also note that there is a parameter called `save_traces`, and by default, it sets as `True`. I set it `False` as I don't want to. Newly added, according to doc:

> save_traces: (only applies to SavedModel format) When enabled, the SavedModel will store the function traces for each layer. This can be disabled so that only the configs of each layer are stored. Defaults to True. Disabling this will decrease serialization time and reduce file size, but it requires that all custom layers/models implement a get_config() method.

---

Also FYI, as you save the entire model, I like to remind you to use the `custom_object` parameter while loading the model if you've custom layer-like stuff.

```
new_moedl = keras.models.load_model(
    "my_model", custom_objects={"CustomModel": CustomModel}
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have one question if you could answer: not sure what custom_object does. Could you give a small example? Ty

Comment: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280161/saving-keras-models-with-custom-layers

Comment: Thanks :) Have a nice day