# Why is saved model performing differently than the trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save a trained TensorFlow model with some custom layers, which is trained in the following way:

```
model_scratch = models.Sequential()
model_scratch.add(Dense(80, activation='relu', input_dim=(22)))
model_scratch.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model_scratch.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model_scratch.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
auto_srelu=AutoSRELU()
model_scratch.add(auto_srelu)
model_scratch.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model_scratch.add(auto_srelu)
model_scratch.add(BatchNormalization())
model_scratch.add(Dense(15, activation='softmax'))
model_scratch.compile(optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])

model_scratch.fit(X_train_pw, y_train_pw , epochs=50, batch_size = 64, validation_data=(X_test_pw, y_test_pw),verbose=0)
```

The dataset is loaded using `train_test_split` and with a fixed random seed so the dataset is the same.

And I load the model in the following way :

```
pw_scratch = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_scratch.h5', custom_objects=dependencies)
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280161/saving-keras-models-with-custom-layers) to save learn how to save custom layers and load them in a **different** notebook. This is how the `model.evaluate()` works just after training and on the trained model. The same metrics on the saved model are significantly as compared to just after training the model:

*Just After Training:*

```
model_scratch.evaluate(X_train, y_train_pw)
model_scratch.save('model_scratch.h5')  <-----This is how I save the model
```

*Output*

```
206/206 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1020 - acc: 0.9648 - f1_m: 0.9647 - precision_m: 0.9664 - recall_m: 0.9630
[0.10201320797204971,
 0.9647523760795593,
 0.9646635055541992,
 0.9664011597633362,
 0.9629854559898376]
```

After loading the model:

```
dependencies = {
     'f1_m': f1_m,
     'precision_m': precision_m,
     'recall_m': recall_m,
     'AutoSRELU': AutoSRELU
}
pw_scratch = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_scratch.h5', custom_objects=dependencies)
pw_scratch.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
```

*Output*

```
206/206 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 14.8583 - acc: 0.1541 - f1_m: 0.1541 - precision_m: 0.1541 - recall_m: 0.1541
[14.858280181884766,
 0.15405651926994324,
 0.15409861505031586,
 0.15409862995147705,
 0.15409862995147705]
```

I tried training and saving the models multiple times, but I get different (loaded model is always worse) and both the results are **never** the same. Why is this happening?

The custom layer `AutoSRELU` used above has the following definition:

```
initializer0 = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval = -1, maxval =1)
initializer1 = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval = 0.5, maxval =3)

 
class MinMaxConstraint(keras.constraints.Constraint):
    def __init__(self, minval, maxval):
        self.minval = tf.constant(minval ,dtype='float32')
        self.maxval = tf.constant(maxval ,dtype='float32')
    def __call__(self, w):
        tf.cond(tf.greater(self.minval,w)
                , lambda: w + (self.minval - w)
                , lambda: tf.cond(tf.greater(w,self.maxval)
                                  , lambda: w - (w - self.maxval)
                                  , lambda: w))
    def get_config(self):
        return {'Lower Bound': self.minval, 'Upper Bound':self.maxval}
 
 

def srelu(inputs, k1, k2):
    cond1 = tf.cast(tf.math.less(inputs, 0.0), tf.float32)
    cond2 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(inputs, 0.0), tf.float32)
    a = tf.math.multiply(cond1, tf.add(k1,tf.multiply(0.3, inputs)))
    b = tf.math.multiply(cond2, tf.add(k1,tf.multiply(k2, inputs)))
    outputs = a + b
    return outputs
    

class AutoSRELU(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, trainable = True, **kwargs):
        super(AutoSRELU, self).__init__()
        self.k1 = self.add_weight(name='k', shape = (), initializer=initializer0, trainable=trainable)#, constraint=keras.constraints.NonNeg())
        self.k2 = self.add_weight(name='n', shape = (), initializer=initializer1, trainable=trainable)#, constraint=MinMaxConstraint(1,10))
    def call(self, inputs):
        return srelu(inputs, self.k1, self.k2)
```

Comment: What seems strange is that you  load from `model_scratch.h5` while you save `model_scratch_auto` at `model_scratch_auto1.h5` and perform evaluate at `model_scratch` . Is there something that I miss?

Comment: No that was my mistake while typing the question, I am loading the correct model. I was just experimenting with the code and that's why I must've made a mistake while copy-pasting it here.

Comment: First of all, I would like to mention that f1 micro, recall micro and precision micro have the same value for multi-class problems so you dont really have to track all of them (you will make your training faster). Second, as your code says, you still save `model_scratch_auto.save('model_scratch.h5')` instead of `model_scratch.save('model_scratch.h5')`. Is this another typo or your code?

Comment: Okay, I will change that. Yeah that's a typo only, extremely sorry I was a bit hasty in copying the code to here so made some errors in doing that. Anyway, I'll still run it again and let you know if the results are the same or not. Do you think this is something that should happen though?

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: I had tried that out, there wasn't any error related to the name. I figured out which layer was causing the error but didn't know how to correct it so I posted another question with no typos and a reproducible example.